# Realtek HD Audio Driver does not detect external mic in combo jack

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, microphone, realtek-hd-audio

I have ASUS N550JV laptop with combo 3.5mm audio jack, manuel says so. I have Windows 10. However, when I plug in 4 pole 3.5mm mobile phone earbuds, it does not detect external microphone. A window pops up and asks what I plugged in, headset or speaker. I choose headset but external mic does not work, only sound comes me via earbuds. I have searched this problem and people say there is an option in the Realtek HD Audio Manager that allows using both mic and headphone in the same device. But I do not have such an option. Windows Update does not detect update for Realtek sound driver, I still have a version from 2015. Also, I have checked out BIOS settings and there is nothing about audio. There is no update option for soundcart driver in manufacturer website. Is there any solution? Thanks.

Comment: I had something similar a year or so ago.  Dell laptop, same audio.  I seem to remember uninstalling and completely reinstalling the drivers before it started working again.

Comment: Is there a tool or something that is doing this process automatically?

Comment: Same problem. I installed the newest, then previous version of realtek (the one that has the tray icon, without sucess). Tray icon version let choose external micro, but does not work.